# "keytool error: java.lang.NullPointerException: invalid null input" when creating keystore

Tags: java, ssl, server, keytool, ionos

I am trying to update a keystore with a renewed SSL certificate that I downloaded from my Ionos webhost.

I downloaded the PFX file after inputing my private key and password into their PFX creation tool and checked an option to "include intermediate certificates" (this is what I have always done in the past).

When I ran keytool to update the keystore this is the command I used:

```
keytool -importkeystore -srckeystore example.com_private_key.pfx -srcstoretype pkcs12 -destkeystore mykeystore.jks -deststoretype JKS
```

It asks me to enter some passwords and then asks me if I wanted to override the alias. After entering "yes" it gave me the "Invalid null input" error.

I also tried creating a new keystore instead of updating the old one and after entering the passwords I received the same error.

I still have my old PFX file from last year and keytool doesn't give the error when creating a keystore with that.

I also tried reissuing the private key and redownloading the PFX with and without the intermediate certificate option but got the same error.

I don't know where to even start to find out how to overcome this issue. My only assumption is that there is something wrong with the new PFX file but don't know how I can verify it or troubleshoot.

Any suggestions?

EDIT:

I decided to run keytool -list on the PFX file and this was the output

```
>keytool -list -v -keystore example.com_private_key.pfx
Enter keystore password:
Keystore type: PKCS12
Keystore provider: SUN

Your keystore contains 1 entry

Alias name: *.example.com
Creation date: 22-Mar-2023
Entry type: PrivateKeyEntry


*******************************************
*******************************************
```

Usually this gives a big list of things but this seems empty.

Comment: There is definitely a privatekey in that PKCS12, the display says so. But either the _certificates_ are not present, or are unreadable -- which might occur if you give a wrong/inconsistent password, but that should cause other error messages as well. Do you have openssl, including on another machine you can use, or can you get it? If so, do `openssl pkcs12 -info -nokeys` on each file to see the encryption options and cert(s), but not the (sensitive) privatekey values, and compare the working to nonworking case.

Comment: I don't know who voted to close this question as not being about software development, but that's certainly wrong; keytool is part of the JDK and the resulting keystores are required as input for many programming tasks. I'm agreeing with Dave above of course. What is required for Java keystores is that there is a certificate chain that is directly associated with the private key (possibly excluding root cert), starting with the leaf certificate. Separate certificates are commonly considered trust points instead.

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 thank you for your suggestion, I was able to compare them and they seem almost identical except that the non working one has `Bag Attributes: <Empty Attributes>` where as the working one had a `friendlyname` and `localKeyID` inside the `Bag Attributes`. Since I had OpenSSL I downloaded the cert, intermediate cert and private key from my host and used OpenSSL to create a new PFX and it worked. It had the same bag attributes as the working one and keytool was able to successfully import them. So I assume the Empty Attributes thing was the issue?

Comment: Curtis: yes, or more exactly the lack of `localKeyID`, which is used to link the privatekey to the matching cert (since the PKCS12 format allows more than one of each, even though you aren't doing so here). The Sun/Oracle/OpenJDK provider doesn't _need_ `friendlyName`, but is easier to use with.

Comment: @Curtis - was was the final resolution here?  How did you get the localKeyID populated?

Comment: @user2857108 I believe it gets created when you make the PFX file with OpenSSL. Its been a while since I did that though so Im not entirely sure anymore.

Comment: @user2857108 I just posted an answer to this question with full detailed steps explaining what I did to get a working PFX file. Hope that helps you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following the advice from @dave_thompson_085 I was able to solve this issue.

#### What caused the error:

The `Invalid null input` **error** from `keytool` was being caused by the fact that the **PFX** file was missing a `friendlyName` and `localKeyID` in its `Bag Attributes` property. Instead of the proper values the `Bag Attributes` were set to a value of `<Empty Attributes>`.

You can check this by using ***OpenSSL*** to get the info from the **bad PFX** file.

Run:

```
openssl pkcs12 -info -nokeys -in "C:\example.com_private_key.pfx"
```

You will get an output that looks like this:

```
MAC Iteration 1024
MAC verified OK
PKCS7 Encrypted data: pbeWithSHA1And40BitRC2-CBC, Iteration 1024
Certificate bag
Bag Attributes: <Empty Attributes>
subject=/CN=*.example.com
issuer=/C=US/O=Example CA/OU=www.exampleca.com/CN=Example CA
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
MIICwDCCAmagAwIBAgIBATANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQUFADCBtjELMAkGA1UEBhMCVVMx
...
...
zYnRrIjp7ImFjdGlvbiI6IlJPTEVfQ09NUExFVEVEIiwicmVwb3NpdG9yeSI6Imh
0dHA6024Ly9leGFtcGxlLmNvbSJ9fSwidGltZXN0YW1wIjoxNTcxMTQxMjg0fQ==
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
Certificate bag
Bag Attributes: <Empty Attributes>
subject=/C=US/O=Example CA/OU=www.exampleca.com/CN=Example CA
issuer=/C=US/O=Example CA/OU=www.exampleca.com/CN=Example CA Root
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
MIICwDCCAmagAwIBAgIBATANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQUFADA7MQswCQYDVQQGEwJVUzET
...
...
Qnl0ZXMgYW5kIEhhY2thdGhvbi9yZWFsIENBIHRlc3QgaW5zdGFuY2Ugc3lzLg==
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
PKCS7 Data
Shrouded Keybag: pbeWithSHA1And3-KeyTripleDES-CBC, Iteration 1024
```

You will see that `Bag Attributes` has a value of `<Empty Attributes>` for both certificates.

#### The solution:

To fix this I manually created a new **PFX** file using ***OpenSSL***.

First, obtain the following files from your ***SSL provider***:

- Private Key (`example.com_private_key.key`)
- SSL Certificate (`example.com_ssl_certificate.cer`)
- Intermediate Certificate (`example.com_ssl_certificate_INTERMEDIATE.cer`)

Then use ***OpenSSL*** to create your new **PFX** file by running the following command:

```
openssl pkcs12 -export -out "C:\example.com_private_key_fixed.pfx" -name "*.example.com" -inkey "C:\example.com_private_key.key" -in "C:\example.com_ssl_certificate.cer" -certfile "C:\example.com_ssl_certificate_INTERMEDIATE.cer" -caname "Example Certificate Authority Friendly Name"
```

*Replace the properties with your appropriate file paths and `friendlyName` values.*

According to Dave the `friendlyName` properties aren't needed but I included them because they were in my last working **PFX** file.

#### Verify your new PFX file

You can use ***OpenSSL*** to verify that the `Bag Attributes` have been set correctly.

Run:

```
openssl pkcs12 -info -nokeys -in "C:\example.com_private_key_fixed.pfx"
```

You will get an output that looks like this:

```
MAC Iteration 1024
MAC verified OK
PKCS7 Encrypted data: pbeWithSHA1And40BitRC2-CBC, Iteration 1024
Certificate bag
Bag Attributes:
    localKeyID: 01 02 03 04 05 06 07 08 09 0A 0B 0C 0D 0E 0F 10
    friendlyName: *.example.com
subject=/CN=*.example.com
issuer=/C=US/O=Example CA/OU=www.exampleca.com/CN=Example CA
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
MIICwDCCAmagAwIBAgIBATANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQUFADCBtjELMAkGA1UEBhMCVVMx
...
...
zYnRrIjp7ImFjdGlvbiI6IlJPTEVfQ09NUExFVEVEIiwicmVwb3NpdG9yeSI6Imh
0dHA6024Ly9leGFtcGxlLmNvbSJ9fSwidGltZXN0YW1wIjoxNTcxMTQxMjg0fQ==
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
Certificate bag
Bag Attributes:
    friendlyName: Example Certificate Authority Friendly Name
subject=/C=US/O=Example CA/OU=www.exampleca.com/CN=Example CA
issuer=/C=US/O=Example CA/OU=www.exampleca.com/CN=Example CA Root
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
MIICwDCCAmagAwIBAgIBATANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQUFADA7MQswCQYDVQQGEwJVUzET
...
...
Qnl0ZXMgYW5kIEhhY2thdGhvbi9yZWFsIENBIHRlc3QgaW5zdGFuY2Ugc3lzLg==
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
PKCS7 Data
Shrouded Keybag: pbeWithSHA1And3-KeyTripleDES-CBC, Iteration 1024
```

You will see that `Bag Attributes` is now correctly set. The **PFX** file should also now be able to be imported with `keytool` without getting the `Invalid null input" error.

#### Extra info:

I don't know if this matters, but the `friendlyName` of my Intermediate Certificate in the last working **PFX** file that I downloaded from my web host was the exact same as the Intermediate Certificate's `subject` property, but with the **slashes** replaced by **commas** and the order **reversed**.

So

```
`subject=/C=US/O=Example CA/OU=www.exampleca.com/CN=Example CA`
```

would become:

```
`-caname "CN=Example CA,OU=www.exampleca.com,O=Example CA,C=US"`
```

when inputting the Certificate Authority's `friendlyName`.

Again the `friendlyName` might not matter, but I thought it was worth mentioning since it was something I noticed while looking at my older working **PFX** files that had been generated by my web host.

#### Thanks:

Big thanks to @dave_thompson_085 once more! Just had to renew my SSL Certificates for the year, but my web host still hasn't sorted out their PFX file issue. Had to DIY it with OpenSSL again. Cheers for the help!